# If I use Firebase in an ios application, do i need to fill out an Export Compliance report?

Tags: ios, firebase

In an app I'm developing, I use firebase for my backend. Would this alone have me fill out an export compliance report yearly?

Comment: You are asking for legal advice?

Comment: in the apple upload process it asks 
"Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography?"
would this question be better to ask to a lawyer?